# FLOSS/Free solution to generate PDF documents in Python?

Tags: python, pdf, pdf-generation

What is the easiest way to generate PDF documents with embedded fonts in Python without a commercial/restricted library?

I want to generate documents with tabular data and headers/footers. I've tried reportlab, but while powerful, it seems rather difficult to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create the document in html and then use [WKHTMLTOPDF](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) to convert to pdf...  It is licensed GNU but it is a pretty good tool.

Comment: HTML+CSS always seemed the obvious choice, but what about headers and footers? As far as I understand, WebKit doesn't support the paged media CSS3 to that degree, does it? I've seen standalone HTML-to-PDF tools which utilized CSS3, but they were generally a bit broken.

Comment: check out the manual at http://madalgo.au.dk/~jakobt/wkhtmltopdf-0.9.9-doc.html.  Headers and footers are indeed supported with the standalone (precompiled version)...

Comment: This seems pretty neat. As WKHTMLTOPDF is under the regular GPL rather than the AGPL, the license shouldn't be a problem when I'm using the standalone binary, right?

Comment: Yea actually it looks like you should be fine as long as it you just use the compiled .exe

Answer (score 1):

I've used PISA and been very, very happy.  It uses reportlab for you.

http://www.xhtml2pdf.com/doc/pisa-en.html

Comment: I looked into this one before and noticed the author hadn't made any commits to after moving the project to github. I remember having tried it and running into weird rendering bugs when using headers and footers. Is there a particular version I should go for?

Comment: @Alan: "weird rendering bugs when using headers and footers"?  You might want to open another question addressing this specifically.  It's impossible to discuss in comments, and not focused on the  essential question here.

Comment: Might be mixing up xhtml2pdf with another library, but I remember giving it a try and ending up with wonky margins and paddings whenever I used headers or footers. I'll give it another try if wkhtmltopdf doesn't work out for me. This seems to suggest xhtml2pdf/pisa is kinda dead: http://groups.google.com/group/xhtml2pdf/browse_thread/thread/32dcee769245fc8f

Answer (score 0):

Be careful if you want to be able to extract the tabular data later from the PDFs. They need to be created as Structured Content or there will be no tabular metadata in the PDF file.

Comment: I don't care much about the data being extractable. I would just generate HTML with CSS3 if paged media support in modern browsers were better. I really just want something I can use to generate a printable or print-like document (e.g. invoices, reports). I used FPDF in PHP and Java, but its font support is atrocious.